# Select2 + Prototype stopped propagation on events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype, jquery-select2

I am using Select2 library to achieve a asked functionality.

I have 2 selects: First one is for countries select and second one is for regions select.
Whenever the country select is changed to another value the second one ( regions ) must update with regions according to that country.

From a class made in prototype for original regions select I added and observer for the original country select

```
Event.observe(this.countrySelect, 'change', this.update.bind(this));
```

Country and region select has different prototype class.

Without Select2 everything is working ok and change is captured and executing the update function.

But when I initialize select2 on country select element it will listen only for the onChange event in the select 2 and die. I can see that on the original element there are 2 listeners attached.

Tried with trigger, triggerHandler to force execution of second listener but not working.

Can someone please give me an ideea for this one?

// Edit - more code added

// Html

```
<select id="countries"></<select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    new CountrySelect('#countries',jsonCountries);
</script>

<select id="regions"></select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    new RegionsSelect('#regions','#countries',jsonCountriesRegions);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
CountrySelect = Class.create();

CountrySelect.prototype = {
    initialize: function(countryElement,countries) {
        // Initializations here
    },

    selectize: function() {
        var transformedSelectObject = jQuery(this.countryElement).select2();

        jQuery(transformedSelectObject).change(function(event) {
            // The code below is not correct. Enters infinite loop
            jQuery(this.countryElement).triggerHandler('change');
        });

    },

    update: function() {
        // Updates selector of country
        this.selectize();
    }
}
RegionsSelect= Class.create();

RegionsSelect.prototype = {
    initialize: function(countryElement,regionElement,countriesWithMappedRegions) {
        // Initializations here

        Event.observe(this.countryElement, 'change', this.update.bind(this));

    },

    selectize: function() {
        var transformedSelectObject = jQuery(this.regionElement).select2();
    },

    update: function() {
        // Updates selector of regions
        this.selectize();
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Consider sharing more code for us to review and help.

Comment: Hello Stphane, updated the question with more code. Thank you